# How to convert the hexa code to text in python

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, unicode, encode

I have this string which I get from web scrapping. I want to convert this hex code to normal text. I use encode("utf-8")still it is not working

```
text = 'Hospital Nossa Senhora da Concei&#xE7;&#xE3;o, Porto Alegre, Brazil,Hospital de Base S&#xE3;o Jos&#xE9; do Rio Preto, S&#xE3;o Jos&#xE9; Do Rio Preto, Brazil'
text = text.encode("ut-8")
```

The expected output must be **Hospital Nossa Senhora da Conceição, Porto Alegre, Brazil, Hospital de Base São José do Rio Preto, São José Do Rio Preto**

I also tried

```
text.encode('utf-8').decode('unicode-escape')
```

but still it is not working. Could anyone help in this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply [`html` — HyperText Markup Language support](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/html.html).

> This module defines utilities to manipulate HTML.
>
> …
>
> `html.unescape(s)`
>
> Convert all named and numeric character references (e.g. `&gt;`,
> `&#62;`, `&#x3e;`) in the string s to the corresponding Unicode
> characters. This function uses the rules defined by the HTML 5
> standard for both valid and invalid character references, and the list
> of HTML 5 named character references.
>
> *New in version 3.4.*

```
import html

text = 'Hospital Nossa Senhora da Concei&#xE7;&#xE3;o, Porto Alegre, Brazil,Hospital de Base S&#xE3;o Jos&#xE9; do Rio Preto, S&#xE3;o Jos&#xE9; Do Rio Preto, Brazil'
unescaped_text = html.unescape(text)
print( unescaped_text)
```

**Output**: `.\SO\72657237.py`

> Hospital Nossa Senhora da Conceição, Porto Alegre, Brazil,Hospital de
> Base São José do Rio Preto, São José Do Rio Preto, Brazil